# How to update the array in nested array of objects in react state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js

I want to update age array

```
  const [varient, setVarient] = useState([
    { id: 0, targets: { ageGender: { age: [], gender: [] }, parameterData } },
  ]);
```

After updating

Result

```
Array = [
    { id: 0, targets: { ageGender: { age: [12,13], gender: [] }, parameterData } },
  ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
 const addAge = (age: number) => {
    const newVarient = [...varient];
    newVarient[0].targets.ageGender.age.push(age);
    setVarient(newVarient);
  }
```

Comment: i like the fact that you are not mutating the state.

Comment: Spreading an array only does a shallow copy, so all objects within the array are the same references to the ones in the current state, hence `newVarient[0].targets.ageGender.age.push(age)` is mutating the current state.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your state and the new value is computed based on the previous 'snapshot' (e.g. value) of your state, then you can  pass a function to setState. This function takes in the previous snapshot and returns an updated value. This is the recommended approach by the React team. Read more about this concept in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) under subheading 'Functional updates'.

I have added a working [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/update-state-96l07p) to answer your question.