# bad value includes() react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to make a function that add a keyword if is not already in the array, if it is shows a error message, but the problem is that the `includes()` method doesn't work properly, it shows false first (when a word is not in the array), then true (because it is in the array) and then false again if i don't change the word.

I don't know why this is happening but it happens also with `indexOf()`. Maybe its a react problem with rendering or something like that.

Between if its another way to take an input value and do this, it is welcome

```
const [repeatedKeyWord, setRepeatedKeyWord] = useState(false)

let keyWords = []

const addKeyword = () => {
    let keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
    const exist = keyWords.includes(keyword);
    console.log(exist)

    if (keyword && !exist){
        console.log('in')
        keyWords.push(keyword)
        setRepeatedKeyWord(false)   
    }

    setRepeatedKeyWord(exist? true : false)
    console.log(keyWords)
}
<PlusIcon className="w-6 text-firstColor cursor-pointer mr-2" onClick={addKeyword} />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must store your keywords in `useState`, otherwise you lose the value between re-renders of your component. Thereafter, you can use `.includes` on your array. React ensures that you'll always have the latest value (e.g. 'snapshot' of your state).

Also note that when you are trying to compute a new state value (i.e. updating your array) you are dependent on the previous value of your state. If that is the case, you can pass a function to the setState function. Have a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73436677/how-to-update-the-array-in-nested-array-of-objects-in-react-state/73437267#73437267) where I have included a link to a working codesandbox for updating previous state values.

As a side note, I would suggest to avoid using `let` to declare your variables. Only use the let keyword if you are certain that you will re-assign a new value to your variable. Otherwise using `const` might be better to avoid mistakes.

```
const [keywords, setKeyWords] = useState([])

const addKeyword = () => {
  const keyword = document.getElementById('keyword').value;

  return setKeywords((prevState) => {
    if (prevState.includes(keyword)) {
       return [...prevState] 
   }
    return [...prevState, keyword]
  })
}
<PlusIcon className="w-6 text-firstColor cursor-pointer mr-2" onClick={addKeyword}
```

Comment: Thanks, do u have something to learn how react re renders works? cause sometimes i dont know how works and its confusing

Comment: You're welcome! I also added another codesandbox example (https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-chihiro-y7w6o0?file=/src/App.tsx). I recently came across a good blog post about re-renders in React. You can check it out here: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/why-react-re-renders/